# How do I create a simple local Typescript node module?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've got multiple node modules in the same repo (I'm using them in lambdas), and I have some common functions that I want to include in each of those modules.

So I've created a seperate node module in a the root of my repo called `common`

This module has a single index.ts file and for the purpose of this example has a function called `commonFunction()`

All I want to be able to do now is reference that module in my other node modules using the following:

```
import { commonFunction } from 'common';
```

You would think this should be pretty straight forward, but I think the examples I've followed have led me astray.  I keep getting errors such as `Cannot find module 'common' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with a bog standard example?

Answer (score -2):

here is a link to the documentation of import and export modules in ts:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html